# How to find out whether an element is in a hidden iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Using jQuery, one can easily find out whether a particular element is visible using

```
$(element).is(':visible')
```

While having some limitations (doesn't cover css visibility hidden or the actual visibility in the viewport, i.e. whether it's covered by other elements or scrolled away), I find it being useful for my scenario. **The catch is, it only works within one iframe.**

If the element has any parent within its document with `display:none;`, it returns false. If the whole document is included in an iframe which has `display:none`, it returns true. Is it possible to somehow detect this in another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the window's [frameElement](http://help.dottoro.com/ljsokerh.php) property works in all browsers and delivers the current iframe where the window is contained (if cross-domain restriction doesn't apply, which was my case).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems like you have to call top (parent) document within an iframe, then search for specific iframe and check if it's visible.

You'll probably  have to have same domain/subdomain for this to work, but anyway:

Let's assume you know iframe id/class (you have to).

```
if ($(top).find('#iframeID').is(':visible')) {
  // iframe is visible
} else {
 // iframe is NOT visible
}
```

Can't guarantee correct work.

Answer (score -1):

not possible afaik. an iframe is basically a different site and as such guarded against xss. simply don't use iframes but server-side includes.

Comment: An iframe is only 'guarded against XSS' if it's from a different (sub)domain and neither the parent document nor the iframe adjust `document.domain` for the domains to match (note that you can only do this between subdomains to their parent domains, eg `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` can both set it to `example.com` and can then communicate).